# How to run TRON 2.0 on windows 7?

Tags: tron-2.0

So, I've installed TRON 2.0, and due to some strange star alignment it runs properly once in a while. Also I do not get ant mouse cursor at all in-game.

I have all patched and running latest Killer App Mod.
I'm on Win7x64 and all drivers are allright and updated.

Given this, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

It appears that the launcher whindow shows after *some* time (at least 3 hours) when it doesn't show immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: *I needed to bypass `TRON.exe`.* I hope that I'm helping someone by sharing my own solution.

So, the link on your desktop points to `TRON.exe`, which is simply a launcher that invokes the game engine (Lithtech.exe) with the proper parameters.

By executing it you should be able to run Tron 2.0 regardless of the launcher. This is the command I use to run the game:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Buena Vista Interactive\Tron 2.0\Lithtech.exe"  -rez GAME.rez -rez sound.rez -rez GAME2.rez -rez custom -rez gamep5.rez -rez gamep6.rez -rez gamep5.rez -rez gamep6.rez -rez "C:\Program Files (x86)\Buena Vista Interactive\Tron 2.0\tcdg\game" +multiplayer 0  +DisableMusic 0 +DisableSound 0 +DisableJoystick 1 +DisableTripBuf 0 +DisableHardwareCursor 0 +DisableHardwareSound 0 +DisableSoundFilters 0

Also, the fix for the mouse cursor problerm (at least in my case) is setting the compatibility mode of the windows executable to "Windows 2000" and "disable visual themes" (i don't know how it is written in English, my UI is in Italian).